# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, composition, derived-class

Here are the instructions:

In Chapter 10, the class `clockType` was designed to implement the time of day in a program. Certain applications, in addition to hours, minutes, and seconds, might require you to store the time zone.
Derive the class `extClockType` from the class `clockType`
by adding a member variable to store the time zone. Add the necessary member functions and constructors to make the class functional. Also, write the definitions of the member functions and the constructors. Finally, write a test program to test your class.

Here are my files:

**clockType.h**
​

```
//clockType.h, the specification file for the class clockType

#ifndef H_ClockType

#define H_ClockType

class clockType

{

public:

void setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);

//Function to set the time.

//The time is set according to the parameters.

//Postcondition: hr = hours; min = minutes;

// sec = seconds

// The function checks whether the values of

// hours, minutes, and seconds are valid. If a

// value is invalid, the default value 0 is

// assigned.

​

void getTime(int& hours, int& minutes, int& seconds) const;

//Function to return the time.

//Postcondition: hours = hr; minutes = min;

// seconds = sec

​

void printTime() const;

//Function to print the time.

//Postcondition: The time is printed in the form

// hh:mm:ss.

​

void incrementSeconds();

//Function to increment the time by one second.

//Postcondition: The time is incremented by one

// second.

// If the before-increment time is 23:59:59, the

// time is reset to 00:00:00.

​

void incrementMinutes();

//Function to increment the time by one minute.

//Postcondition: The time is incremented by one

// minute.

// If the before-increment time is 23:59:53,

// the time is reset to 00:00:53.

​

void incrementHours();

//Function to increment the time by one hour.

//Postcondition: The time is incremented by one

// hour.

// If the before-increment time is 23:45:53, the

// time is reset to 00:45:53.

​

bool equalTime(const clockType& otherClock) const;

//Function to compare the two times.

//Postcondition: Returns true if this time is

// equal to otherClock; otherwise,

// returns false.

​

clockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);

//constructor with parameters

//The time is set according to the parameters.

//Postcondition: hr = hours; min = minutes;

// sec = seconds

// The constructor checks whether the values of

// hours, minutes, and seconds are valid. If a

// value is invalid, the default value 0 is

// assigned.

​

clockType();

//default constructor with parameters

//The time is set to 00:00:00.

//Postcondition: hr = 0; min = 0; sec = 0

private:

int hr; //variable to store the hours

int min; //variable to store the minutes

int sec; //variable to store the seconds

};

#endif
```

**clockTypeImp.cpp**

```
//Implementation File for the class clockType

#include <iostream>

#include "clockType.h"

​

using namespace std;

void clockType::setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)

{

if (0 <= hours && hours < 24)

hr = hours;

else

hr = 0;

​

if (0 <= minutes && minutes < 60)

min = minutes;

else

min = 0;

​

if (0 <= seconds && seconds < 60)

sec = seconds;

else

sec = 0;

}

​

void clockType::getTime(int& hours, int& minutes,

int& seconds) const

{

hours = hr;

minutes = min;

seconds = sec;

}

​

void clockType::incrementHours()

{

hr++;

if (hr > 23)

hr = 0;

}

​

void clockType::incrementMinutes()

{

min++;

if (min > 59)

{

min = 0;

incrementHours();

}

}

​

void clockType::incrementSeconds()

{

sec++;

​

if (sec > 59)

{

sec = 0;

incrementMinutes();

}

}

​

void clockType::printTime() const

{

if (hr < 10)

cout << "0";

cout << hr << ":";

​

if (min < 10)

cout << "0";

cout << min << ":";

​

if (sec < 10)

cout << "0";

cout << sec;

}

​

bool clockType::equalTime(const clockType& otherClock) const

{

return (hr == otherClock.hr

&& min == otherClock.min

&& sec == otherClock.sec);

}

​

clockType::clockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)

{

if (0 <= hours && hours < 24)

hr = hours;

else

hr = 0;

​

if (0 <= minutes && minutes < 60)

min = minutes;

else

min = 0;

​

if (0 <= seconds && seconds < 60)

sec = seconds;

else

sec = 0;

}

​

clockType::clockType() //default constructor

{

hr = 0;

min = 0;

sec = 0;

}

​
```

(these first 2 files are given)

(starting here is where i create the code)

**extClockType.h**

```
​

#ifndef H_extClockType

#define H_extClockType

#include<iostream>

#include "clockType.h"

using namespace std;

​

class extClockType: public clockType

{

public:

extClockType();

extClockType(int, int, int, string);

void setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, string zone);

string printTimezone();

string getTimezone();

private:

string zone;

};

#endif
```

**extClockTypeImp.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "clockType.h"

#include "extClockType.h"

​

using namespace std;

extClockType::extClockType(): clockType()

{

zone = "na";

}

​

extClockType::extClockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, string time_zone)

{

clockType::setTime(hours, minutes, seconds);

zone = time_zone;

}

void extClockType::setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, string zone)

{

clockType::setTime(hours, minutes, seconds);

}

string extClockType::getTimezone()

{

return zone;

}

​

string extClockType::printTimezone()

{

clockType::printTime();

cout << " " << zone << endl;

return 0;

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <string>

#include <iomanip>

#include <iostream>

#include "clockType.h"

#include "extClockType.h"

​

using namespace std;

​

int main()

{

extClockType time1(5, 10, 34, "CST");

cout << "Time 1: ";

time1.printTimezone();

cout<<endl;

extClockType time2;

time2.setTime(12, 45, 59, "PST");

cout<< "Time 2: ";

time2.printTimezone();

cout<<endl;

​

time2.incrementSeconds();

cout<< "After incrementing time 2 by one second, Time 2:";

time2.printTime();

}

​
```

This is my error message:

​

```
Time 1: 05:10:34 CST

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'

what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

​

Sorry for the post being long I just wanted to show all of the files I'm working with. If anyone is willing to try to help me that would be a huge help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format the source as code, so that it's easier for readers to interpret. You can either highlight the code and click the `{}` button in the toolbar, or indent each line by four (4) spaces. Please be sure to indent the code itself, too, as if it were an actual source file.

Comment: Is this a typo in the source?  If not, the error is likely here.  What does the cout < do?

 time1.printTimezone();

cout<

extClockType time2;

Comment: Also remove the excessive comments, as they just do nothing except add noise.  We all know what lines of code do.

Comment: @matthewfisher I think you are referring to the line cout<< endl; in between time1.printTimezone(); and extClockType time2; and it is to end the line in between time 1 and time 2

Comment: @paulmckenzie the comments were already in the code when it was given to me so I didn't remove them. sorry.

Comment: Sry the formatting must have confused me a bit.  I note that setTime doesn't actually set the zone.  That should not cause your issue however

Comment: For the purposes of posting code, we don't need to see two screens-worth of comments, when the code is actually 10 or 15 lines.  Take the time to remove these lines before posting code.  For example, that header you posted is [really all this](https://www.ideone.com/IjtZ8y).  Which version do you think is more appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Comment: @matthewfisher Do you know how to get the setTime to set the zone?

Comment: In this method, void extClockType::setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, string zone), change the parameter name to time_zone and add zone = time_zone.  I don't think that is the issue however.  Let me compile it, it will be something simple.

Answer (score 4):

The error simply means that you have called the string constructor:

```
std::string::string(const char *p);
```

with a `NULL` pointer, which is not a valid thing to do.

Use a debugger to find out *exactly* where your code did this, and fix it to not do that.

Comment: There is a second, defaulted, parameter; It doesn't actually change anything though. Also, consider mentioning what is the result of doing something invalid is.

Comment: @Deduplicator Your comment is correct, but I don't think expanding the answer  to include precise details will actually help the OP, and has a chance to confuse him instead.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback it's greatly appreciated!! Do you recommend any debuggers?

Comment: @JarrettBowman The debugger to use depends on the OS you are using. On Linux, build with `g++ -g ...` and use GDB. On Windows, GDB might also work, though I am not sure how well.

Answer (score 1):

One error is this:

```
string extClockType::printTimezone()
{
    clockType::printTime();
    cout << " " << zone << endl;
    return 0;  // This is not legal, converting an int to a std::string
}
```

On return, you are returning `0` and this is being attempted to be converted to a `std::string`.  There is no constructor for `std::string` that takes an `int` argument (in this case `0`).  Instead, an exception will be thrown.

You should return either nothing (thus the function should be declared as returning `void`), or return something that creates a valid `std::string`.

Note:  The constructor that was invoked for `std::string` is the one that takes a single `const char *` argument [(see constructor (5))](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).  In this case, `0` is converted to `nullptr`, thus on return a `std::string(nullptr)` is attempted to be constructed.

Comment: [*Will be thrown is wrong.*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) Throwing an exception is a valid manifestation of UB though.

Comment: "There is no constructor for std::string that takes an int argument (in this case 0). Instead, an exception will be thrown." -- this explanation is incomplete: if there really was no constructor, the code would fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Easy after all

```
string extClockType::printTimezone() {
   ... 
   return 0;
}
```

Change it to this and update the prototype:

```
void extClockType::printTimezone() {
   ... 
   return;
}
```

This tries to construct a std::string with 0 be interpreted as a nullptr.  The return value should likely be void based on the usage.

After the fix, the output is:

Time 1: 05:10:34 CST

Time 2: 12:45:59 na

After incrementing time 2 by one second, Time 2:12:46:00

Note that 'na' is a result of

```
void setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, string zone);
```

not actually setting the 'zone' member variable.

Comment: Thanks for replying! So I understand that it tries to construct a std::string but how do I fix this in my code?

Comment: Added the proper method signature to the answer.  If my answer is helpful then up-voting and accepting it is appreciated.

Comment: I changed it to this:

Comment: void extClockType::printTimezone()
{
clockType::printTime();
cout << " " << zone << endl;
return;
}

Comment: and i get this error: extClockTypeImp.cpp:26:6: error: prototype for ‘void extClockType::printTimezone()’ does not match any in class ‘extClockType’
 void extClockType::printTimezone()
      ^
In file included from extClockTypeImp.cpp:3:0:
extClockType.h:13:8: error: candidate is: std::__cxx11::string extClockType::printTimezone()
 string printTimezone();
        ^
bash: line 2: ./a.out: No such file or directory

Comment: change the declaration of printTimezone in the header file to match

Comment: `return;` at the end of a void function is redundant